# list index out of range error - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote this function for a simple text based hangman game that i'm making, and it's suposed to replace an underline (blank space) with a letter so that it's easier to guess the word. When I run the code it gives me a list index out of range error and I don't understand why.

```
def get_word():
    wordfile = open(file_in_use)
    wordlist = [line.split("\n") for line in wordfile]
    num = random.randint(0,len(wordlist))
    word = linecache.getline(file_in_use, num)
    return word

chosen_word = get_word()
chosen_word = chosen_word.replace("\n", "")

blanks = "_ " * len(chosen_word)
blankslist = []
for character in blanks:
    blankslist.append(character)

chars = []
for character in chosen_word:
    chars.append(character)


attempts = 8
tries = 0
letters_to_give = 0
blanks_to_replace = 0

def give_letters():
    letters_to_give = int(len(chosen_word) / 4 + 1)
    for x in range(letters_to_give):
        pos = random.randint(0,len(chosen_word))
        blankslist[pos] = chars[pos]
```

Comment: what's `chars` here?

Comment: Please show the full error and traceback.  Clearly `pos` is outside the range of either `blankslist` or `chars` and you should trace (`print`) that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
random.randint(0, len(chosen_word))
```

can return `len(chosen_word)`.

Instead, use `random.randrange` if you want `range`-like behaviour.

From the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) docs:

> **random.randrange(stop) random.randrange(start, stop[, step])**
>
> Return a randomly selected element from `range(start, stop, step)`. This is equivalent to `choice(range(start, stop, step))`, but doesn’t
>   actually build a `range` object.
>
> The positional argument pattern matches that of `range()`. Keyword arguments should not be used because the function may use them in
>   unexpected ways.
>
> Changed in version 3.2: `randrange()` is more sophisticated about producing equally distributed values. Formerly it used a style like
>   `int(random()*n)` which could produce slightly uneven distributions.

and

> **random.randint(a, b)**
>
> Return a random integer `N` such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for
>   `randrange(a, b+1)`.

Comment: I don't want a range, I want a random number in a range (for example, the word "monkey" has 6 letters, I would want a random number between 1 and 6"

Comment: Also, from `help(randrange)`: "This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want."

Comment: @J.C. Understood. By "`range`-like behaviour" I meant that the arguments to the `randrange` function behave the same way that the arguments to `range` do. I wasn't implying that it returns a range object when you call it. Hopefully, the information I've just added from the docs makes this clear. :)

Comment: It worked, I guess the only problem was that because the first list index is 0, len(chosen_word), despite having the same characters, would be 1 more than the last list index because len starts with 1, right?

Comment: @J.C. Something like that. An empty list has length 0. A list of length `n` has indices running from 0 upto _but **not** including_ `n`, so the highest index is `n-1`.

Comment: @J.C. BTW, your `give_letters()` function may select the same position multiple times. That may not be a problem, but if you don't want that to happen you could use `random.sample` to select `len(chosen_word) // 4 + 1` different values from `range(len(chosen_word))`

Comment: Finally figured out how to do this